# How to disable WEB developer tools in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to uninstall or disable WEB developer tools in Firefox (Tools - WEB developer). At least, disable their keyboard shortcuts - for example, I really don't want to see Firefox profiler when Shift+F5 is pressed.

Firefox version 21.0, Windows OS (if this is relevant).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In your url input write **about:config**
2. Click I'll be careful when the warning message appears - this will open your config file.
3. Search for `devtools.*.enabled` and set all to `false`.

Comment: I tried this with FF 48.0.1 on Linux. Ctrl+shift+c still opens the Dom and Style inspector.

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev this has probably changed a few times in last 3 years :) The answer is from 2013.

Comment: Yea, that's true. Just wanted to let folks know who use firefox that is not 3 years old :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just for anyone else that is still looking to disable Firefox shortcut Ctrl+Shift+c, you can do so without any Addons/Extensions:

1. Open Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+c or F12)
2. Click "3 dots" menu button in top-right corner
3. Click Settings
4. Disable "Pick an element from the page" restart Firefox

The shortcut still opened DeveloperTools for me until I restarted Firefox.  Now I am able to utilize the shortcut for an extension (StickyNotes).

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The above doesn't work on Linux. Inspectors and all still popup. Afik you can't dissable WEB developer tools in Firefox as it's too deeply integrated.

But with this extension you can dissable shortcuts:
Keybinder: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/keybinder/
(Above is to replace Customizable Shortcuts by Tim Taubert, which is no longer developed/removed)

Config -> Shortcut mapping -> change > (find shortcut, disable).